# regex array multiple parentheses

Tags: php, arrays, regex, linden-scripting-language

Hello I have api function which is basically text in my database

here are the functions I use

```
alpha(integer link, integer face, float alpha);
color(integer link, integer face, vector color, float alpha);
description(integer link, string description);
glow(integer link, integer face, glow);
name(integer link, string name)
position(integer link, vector position)
rotation(integer link, vector rotation)
texture(integer link, integer face, string texture_uuid, vector repeats, vector offsets, float rotation_in_radians)
```

basically what I looking to do is to run a regex to return each of these as array as I tried many times and not having much luck for example in textures I need pick the uuid key which I was using

```
([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})
```

which works fine for that one field but since I have other fields it does not seem to get into array as I not sure how to run multipliable regex

also the link and face can also be negative values as I was using (<[^>]*>|\w+) which works to a degree but not all the api functions

any idea how I can build regex to work on all api function types as I need them in array like this

```
array(
[0] = function,
[1] = link
[2] = face
[3] = texture uuid
[4] = texture repeats
[5] = offset
[6] = rotation
)
```

this is example using the texture function I hope I explained this enough as I having hard time here and looking for help

here example I was using

https://regex101.com/r/vO2gW1/3 as you see its broken as don't pick up uuid

or is there a way with regex or another method to execute these as functions even and keeping there structure as functions to return the data in format I need it for using PHP

Comment: Based on your last try, simply include any additional char you could encounter inside the 2nd part of you alternation... [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vO2gW1/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
^[^(]+(?=\()|(?<=[(,])\s*\K(?:<.*?>|.*?)(?=[,)])
```

It should pick up everything you need. [Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/mN7fG9/2)

What it does is to match anything between the start of the string, commas and parentheses. So it won't work with stuff like `anim(foo())`.

Comment: thanks that seems much better way then I way trying to figure out